# Is there a way to configure the Edge browser to prompt before downloading files?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I would like to be able to rename and specify the destination for downloaded files right at the time of the download.  I don't want to have to visit Downloads, then rename the file, and then move it to its destination.

But I have not found any option in the settings to do that.

Has the functionality, available in all the other browsers, been removed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Edge has that option. It looks like you can't even change the default directory. Microsoft really made Edge way too unconfigurable...

Comment: Hmm, just what I had feared.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no options in place to ask for a location when downloading files. They may work on bringing that functionality to Edge, as confirmed to me by one of the Edge devs in this [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/627219067628331013).

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but just for the ones searching for a solution like me.
As [@SniperXPrime](https://superuser.com/a/1006735/299215) already mentioned, there exists a solution using a registry key. You can find a downloadable reg-file and the complete solution [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/46038-microsoft-edge-download-save-prompt-turn-off-windows-10-a.html#option2).
Basically you have to create /edit the DWORD-entry `EnableSavePrompt` in the following hive:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Download
```

Give it a value of `1` to enable prompting, set it to `0` to disable it again.

Comment: Don't know why this isn't the accepted answer, as it's correct and answers the question! +1 for saving me a load of hassle!

Answer (score 0):

I had the windows edge prompting for download locations at one time with a regedit solution at one point.  So I know it is possible and am trying to find the solution again.

Comment: Please, post an answer with the procedure to solve the asked question. Saying that you're working on it isn't an answer on itself ;)